# mapbox in phonegap having error when there is more than 1 finger touching map

Tags: android, cordova, mapbox

I have a mapbox and it is working but gets an error when multi touch is made on the map

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'y' of undefined at 
http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v0.6.7/mapbox.js:3
```

i believe it is a bug of mapbox based on the post https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox.js/issues/122

but haven't seen a solution for it. Is there a way to disable multi touch in phonegap android as a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest version of mapbox - 1.0.2.

MapBox 1.0+ is a breaking update.  In that I mean that older code may have to be rewritten.